# Save Outlook appointment in Resource Calendar without notification

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, appointment

using EWS, creating an AppointmentItem and adding a resource too. The Appointment get added to Resource Calendar and an email notification goes to Resource Inbox.

But i don't want any email notification just want to get added to Calendar.

I tried using `SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone` but it then doesn't add in Calendar even.

then i tried using
 `Mailbox mbox = new Mailbox(user);

FolderId folder = new
FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mbox);

appointment.Save(folder);` but then it send email notification too besides adding in Calendar.

So, What I want is: "get added in Calendar but don't send me notification".

Answer (score 0):

`SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone` is the correct way to no add a notification.

Try not sending to a folder, but to `WellKnownFolderName.Calendar`

```cs
appointment.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```